# Where is the on-chain architecture explained in the whitepaper applied in Chainlink?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, chainlink

I am quite new to Chainlink. I have read the Whitepaper v1 and several articles about Chainlink, but I can't understand how the explained architecture really works.

Where does the reputation contract, order matching contract and aggregation contract come into the picture? Where and with whom do they interact? From what I could test in API calls and price feeds, I can only choose nodes and jobs, but not reputation.

Also, do the nodes actually bid to receive requests? I didn't find anything about node bid in the documentation. Only payments for running jobs.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.chain.link/docs/architecture-overview/

Comment: @PatrickCollins Yeah, I have, but in the whitepaper it talks about reputation contract, order matching contract and aggregation contract which isn't referenced on the Chainlink Architecture Overview.

I mean, the whitepaper talks about an order-matching smart contract taking bids from oracle providers and there isn't any info about this on the Chainlink docs. Is it that the real architecture is totally different from the one on the whitepaper?